# How are template arguments expanded

Tags: c++, templates

I am confused about the expansion of this template [example one]. If bool b is checked at runtime in the constructor where is b stored ? is it put into the private data section [example two]? or does it become compile time and remove a branched based on the bool? or does it simply "paste" what was passed as a template argument into the if(b) [example 3]

Example one:

```
template<bool b>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test()
        {
            if(b)
            {
                // do something
            }
            else
            {
                // do something else
            }
        }
    };
```

Example two:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        if(b)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }

private:
    bool b = true;
};
```

Example three:

```
//called with Test<true>

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        if(true)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            // do something else - probably removed due too compiler optimization
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 3** is the snippet that more closely resembles what the compiler is doing. It's important to understand that **example 2 is wrong**, as the template parameter is evaluated at compile-time and not injected into the class as a field.

Doing `if(b){ } else { }` where `b` is a template `bool` parameter will require both branches of the `if` statement to be both **parseable** and **well-formed**, even if the compiler will very likely optimize out the branch that doesn't match `b`.

---

If you want guaranteed compile-time branch evaluation, and if you need only the taken branch to be **well-formed**, you can use [`if constexpr(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) in C++17:

```
if constexpr(b)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

...or implement your own `static_if` construct in C++14...

...or use an [explicit template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) in C++11.

I cover all of these techniques in my CppCon 2016 talk, [*"Implementing `static` control flow in C++14"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k).